# 6 wires into single light switch

Tags: wiring, light-fixture

I have a single light switch it like to replace but there are 3 each black and red wires. No earth. What can I replace this with? Would I be able to add a socket outlet?

Comment: Hi @Tasha - as the saying goes a picture is worth a thousand words ...  As to socket - depends on the wire gauge, where it's connected to and juristiction.  For instance where I am lighting circuits are normally 1.5mm conductors, whereas power are at least 2.5mm - so if you had a lighting circuit it's not legal to put a socket (which requires the larger diameter wires) onto it.

Comment: Where are you on this planet and can you post a photo of the inside of the backbox please?

Comment: which ones were connected to the switch? How were they grouped?